# compare data in a JSON::Value variable and then update to file

Tags: c++

I am trying to update a data to two JSON files by providing the filename at run time.

This is the updateTOFile function which will update data stored in JSON variable  to two different  in two different threads.

```
void updateToFile()
    {
        while(runInternalThread)
        {

                std::unique_lock<std::recursive_mutex> invlock(mutex_NodeInvConf);
                FILE * pFile;
                std::string conff =  NodeInvConfiguration.toStyledString();
                pFile = fopen (filename.c_str(), "wb");
                std::ifstream file(filename);
                fwrite (conff.c_str() , sizeof(char), conff.length(), pFile);
                fclose (pFile);
                sync();

        }
    }
```

thread 1:
`std::thread nt(&NodeList::updateToFile,this);`

thread 2:
`std::thread it(&InventoryList::updateToFile,this);`

now it's updating the files even if no data has changed from the previous execution. I want to update the file only if there's any change compared to previously stored one. if there is no change then it should print the data is same.
Can anyone please help with this??
Thanks.

Comment: Off topic: I've never seen such a casual mix of C++11 and C. It seems like perhaps this is all self-taught? Maybe use `ofstream` and `ifstream` instead of C style file handles.

Comment: You may have to open the file, read the contents and compare it with the data that needs to be written. If there is no change in data, you will simply print log about data being same and if not overwrite the content. Or am I missing anything here ?

Comment: @Mahesh you are right. but what i'm asking is how to do that?? can demonstrate the same using my code.

Comment: @Sachin I don't understand: "_...will update data stored in JSON variable to two different_" - Two different _what_?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Two different files

Comment: @Sachin Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57611376/edit) the question and put the clarification in it.

Comment: @TedLyngmo 'NodeInvConfiguration' is a JSON::value variable. I am writing the value stored in  that variable to Json files. Now it is rewriting the data in files even if there is no change in that variable from previous execution. So i want to check whether there is any change in that variable. if so then it should update the file,if there is no change then it should not update, simply exit by printing something.

Comment: @Sachin Instead of clarifying your question in comments, improve the question by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57611376/edit) it. You can also add a tag for the specific json library you are using (`jsoncpp` I guess?).

Answer (score 0):

You can check if it has changed before writing.

```
void updateToFile()
{
    std::string previous;
    while(runInternalThread)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::recursive_mutex> invlock(mutex_NodeInvConf);
        std::string conf =  NodeInvConfiguration.toStyledString();
        if (conf != previous)
        {
            // TODO: error handling missing like in OP
            std::ofstream file(filename);
            file.write (conf.c_str() , conf.length());
            file.close();
            previous = std::move(conf);
            sync();
        }
    }
}
```

However such constant polling in loop is likely inefficient. You may add `Sleep`s to make it less diligent. Other option is to track by `NodeInvConfiguration` itself if it has changed and clear that flag when storing.

Comment: "Other option is to track by NodeInvConfiguration itself if it has changed and clear that flag when storing".  How to do that??

Comment: I don't know, you did not post it.